# What happen if I set a smaller resolution in to a camera which has a constant resolution?

Tags: opencv, camera

I have a USB camera and I know that it has a constant  resolution 1920x1080.

When I use opencv's VideoCapture to set resolution to 1080x720 using following way

```
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1080)
video_capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
```

What is happening essentially?

It subsample from the camera buffer directly or read the whole image and resize to 1080x720?

If opencv subsample from the camera buffer directly, then apply these setting would increase the reading speed right?

If opencv read the whole image and resize to 1080x720, then apply these setting would decrease the reading spped right?

What kind of situation should it belong to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried setting the resolution to different values

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
w = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
for i in range(1, 2000):
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, int(i))
    if w != cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH):
        h = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        w = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        print(str(int(w)), str(int(h)))

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the result I get

```
160 120
320 240
640 480
848 480
960 540
1280 720
```

Since I don't have `1920x1080` option, it can be concluded that `cap.set` property can be used only if the camera supports the desired resolution.

Note that resizing operation is well implemented in OpenCV. So, even for the lowest power computers, such as Raspberry Pi, the time passes for resizing is ignorable compared to other imaging operations. (Unlike Gaussian blur, for instance, whose computational time is also ignorable in normal computers, but the operation takes a lot of time in RPi.)